# How to write the query

Tags: sql-server

I am having one situation, i.e. in one table i am having `Course, Semester and University` Columns, in another table i am having `Book Number, Author, Booktitle, Publication and Year`. For each course, each semester and each university the book differs(i.e., `Book Number, Author, Booktitle, Publication`), what i am have to do is based on the course, semester and university i have to retrieve the values of `Book Number, Author, Booktitle and Publication`. i.e. i am doing B.E. Mech, 2nd year means, the retrieving values of Book Number, Author, Booktitle and Publication should be corresponding to B.E. Mechanical, 2nd year books.

Comment: I can't see any way your two tables are linked?

Comment: Using foreign key, i linked that two tables

Comment: Please provide your actual table definitions separate from the main text so we can see them easily and know their names. `CREATE TABLE Foo(Course char(4))`. I can't see any obvious FK between them in your text description.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Sorry in question i forget to post the foreign key relationship, in Course table also i am having one Book No. column.

Comment: If you store the BookNo in the Course table, you cannot have more than one Book per Course, is this what you want? See my answer how to link any number of Courses to multiple books.

Comment: @StephanB: No, i can have more than one book per course, book name is same, but author varies, we only give the book number, for a single book name i can have more than one author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, there may be more than one Course / Semester / University combination for one book and probably more than one book per Course / Semester / University? This is a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relation and can only be solved by a third table:

```
CsuToBooks
----------
CsuID
BookID
```

When this table is filled, use  two 'LEFT JOIN' relations in your Queries:

```
SELECT Course, Semester, University, BookNumber
FROM csu
LEFT JOIN CsuToBooks ON (csu.ID = CsuToBooks.csuID)
LEFT JOIN Books ON (CsuToBooks.BookID = Books.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a common colum in both tables.For example adding course_id in both tables, so that you can than join both tables by using this common colum

Answer (score 0):

In your first table, add a Book_number column. This will provide a mapping between the 2 tables.
Then you can write the query like

```
Select * from book_table 
where book_table.book_number = course.book_number 
      AND course.course = <course name> 
      AND course.Semester = <semester> 
      AND course.university = <university
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a linking table because (presumably) books and courses have a many-to-many relationship. So you'll have Courses_Books with a CourseID and BookID column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    booknumber,
    author,
    booktitle,
    publication
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    course = 'mech' AND semester = 4
```